# Upgrading my Azure function to .net8 fails with the error Could not load file or assembly 'System.Linq, Version=8.0.0.0

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions, .net-8.0

When upgrading my Azure Functions app from .NET 6 to .NET 8, The build succeed but I get the following error at runtime `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Linq, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.'`

This is my .csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NPOI" Version="2.6.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

How to fix this error ?

Comment: Are you using a variant of Azure Functions that actually supports .NET 8? https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/net-on-azure-functions-august-2023-roadmap-update/ba-p/3910098

Comment: As @MartinCostello pointed out - only out-of-process is supported for now.
It is set in `settings.json`:


- OutOfProcess = "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"
- InProcess = "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need other packages for .NET 8 because you need to use the isolated model.

The easiest way to use the new version is to just create a new project in Visual Studio 2022 v17.8 or later and move your code there.

For the in-process model, they will update to .NET 8 in 2024

Comment: According to https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/net-on-azure-functions-august-2023-roadmap-update/ba-p/3910098#toc-hId--1218956469, support for in-process model will be dropped after .NET 8 anyway, so migrating to isolated model now is probably a sensible way forward.